# Spring Sockjs throwing error while establishing session with server hosted on Websphere -works fine for tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

Off late I have experiencing a lot of issue migrating spring sockjs module from tomcat to Websphere. Everything works fine in a tomcat environment but when I move the same to Websphere with java 1.7, it throws exception in mapping sockjs session ID. Creating and mapping to sockjs session ID is taken care by spring module so not sure what is going wrong, here is the trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebSocketHandler not found for SockJS session id=cik3zk5o
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.PerConnectionWebSocketHandler.getHandler(PerConnectionWebSocketHandler.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.PerConnectionWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(PerConnectionWebSocketHandler.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.delegateMessages(AbstractSockJsSession.java:155)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpReceivingTransportHandler.handleRequestInternal(AbstractHttpReceivingTransportHandler.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.AbstractHttpReceivingTransportHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHttpReceivingTransportHandler.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.DefaultSockJsService.handleTransportRequest(DefaultSockJsService.java:309)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.AbstractSockJsService.handleRequest(AbstractSockJsService.java:295)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(SockJsHttpRequestHandler.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.avaya.cecobrowsega.cobrowse.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3837)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
```

Answer (score 0):

Java API for WebSocket (JSR-356) is a new standard coming in JavaEE 7, so check your application server support for JavaEE7 on running the WebSocket.
WAS doesn't support WebSockets as stated on an IBM forum [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014864997#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014865076)

Comment: Not using WAS websocket support, abstracted with Spring sockjs which falls back to Comet

Comment: Can you paste your spring websocket config here?